Driver install Keysight U2751A
I've bought a used Keysight U2751A and was not able to install a driver on Windows 10 to make it work yet.
Tried to install :

IVI Shared Components : https://www.keysight.com/us/en/lib/software-detail/driver/ivi-shared-components-archive-2925369.html
IVI driver : https://www.keysight.com/us/en/lib/software-detail/driver/u2751a-usb-modular-switch-matrix-ivi-instrument-drivers-1540408.html
Keysight IO Libraries : https://www.keysight.com/us/en/lib/software-detail/computer-software/io-libraries-suite-downloads-2175637.html

Still no driver matched up, but I see it in Devices Manager.
I know the driver talk about compatibility to Windows XP to Windows 7, but should it work on Windows 10 also?

I know the driver talk about compatibility to Windows XP to Windows 7, but should it work on Windows 10 also? No. Actually it6 shouldn't be expected to work.

It seems Keysight has updated drivers that should be compatible with current Windows versions.

@ChanganAuto You found a driver more recent than 2009-03-03 IVI-C Version 1.0.0.0 for U2751A ?

Yes. That date is the first release. If you actually follow the link it shows the current version.
